# Rollup get list of inputs (like esbuild metafile)

Tags: javascript, import, bundler, rollupjs, esbuild

Yo!
I have to use *Rollup*'s JavaScript API to bundle some code directly in the browser (it's an online REPL).
I use **UNPKG** to fetch the packages, and at some point, I need a list of all the imported file, packages etc.

I am used to bundle in the browser using *esbuild*; with *esbuild*'s JavaScript API I can get the list I need, once the bundle is created, by accessing `bundle?.metafile?.inputs`.
The `bundle.metafile.inputs` looks like this :

```js
{
    'a:App.jsx': {
        bytes: 368,
        imports: [
            {
                kind: "import-statement",
                path: "b:https://unpkg.com/react"
            },
            {
                kind: "import-statement",
                path: "b:https://unpkg.com/react-dom/client"
            }
        ]
        },
    'b:https://unpkg.com/react': {
        bytes: 190,
        imports:[
            {
                kind: "require-call",
                path: "b:https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/cjs/react.production.min.js"
            }
        ]
    }
    // ... here all of the other imports and imports of imports
}
```

I looked for something similar in *Rollup*'s documentation but couldn't find any.

Is there anything similar to what I need in *Rollup*'s JS API, or perhaps any existing plugin specific for a usecase without file-system (I mean, with just a virtual one), or do I have to create a similar plugin myself?

Thx in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to [this CodeSandbox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi2qJfz5tr4AhWm_bsIHeGoCy4QFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodesandbox.io%2Fs%2Frollup-in-the-browser-mlfs7&usg=AOvVaw1fLn4eYh2xZZm839h4hrx4),I found out that the result of rollup bundle in the browser is an object structured like so:

```js
{
   "output":[
      {
         "code":"'use strict';\n\nObject.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });\n\nvar lodash = require('lodash');\n\nconst test = lodash.camelSize('yo World');\nconst a = (c, d) => {\n  return [c + d, test];\n};\n\nexports.a = a;\n",
         "dynamicImports":[
            
         ],
         "exports":[
            "a"
         ],
         "facadeModuleId":"/src/index.a.js",
         "fileName":"index.a.js",
         "imports":[
            "lodash"
         ],
         "isDynamicEntry":false,
         "isEntry":true,
         "map":null,
         "modules":{
            "/src/index.a.js":{
               "originalLength":126,
               "removedExports":[
                  
               ],
               "renderedExports":[
                  "a"
               ],
               "renderedLength":91
            }
         },
         "name":"index.a",
         "type":"chunk"
      }
   ]
}
```

Each object in the `output` array, includes a property called `imports`, which is, as the name suggests, an array listing all of the imports  in that bundle.